# Swashbuckle makes all route parameter mandatory for endpoints with same verb but multiple routes in asp.net core 3.1 api swagger ui

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.1, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm working on `asp.net core 2.2` project and upgrading to `asp.net core 3.1` and also upgrading the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` to `5.0.0`. After upgrading I can see change in the swagger generated endpoints.

I have a endpoint for `[HttpDelete]` with two different routes as shown below:

```cs
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
[HttpDelete("{id}/some/{anotherId}")]
public IActionResult Delete(int id, int anotherId) 
{
    return NoContent();
}
```

**`[HttpDelete("{id}")]`**

Only `id` parameter should be required here. But both `id` and `anotherId` parameter are also marked required here. **This is wrong**.

[image]

**`[HttpDelete("{id}/some/{anotherId}")]`**

Both `id` and `anotherId` parameter should be required here. **This is correct.**

[image]

Here is my `Startup.cs`:

**ConfigureServices:**

```cs
services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
{
    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VV";
});

services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
    options.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-api-version");
});

var apiVersionDescriptionProvider =
    services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();

services
    .AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    foreach (var description in apiVersionDescriptionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc(
            $"TestDocumentOpenAPISpecification{description.GroupName}",
            new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "Test Document API",
                Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString(),
                Description = "Test",
                Contact = new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiContact
                {
                    Email = "Test@test.com",
                    Name = "Test Team",
                    Url = new Uri("https://www.test.com")
                }
            });
    }

    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = "Input your JWT Authorization header to access this API. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[] { }
        }
    });

    options.DocInclusionPredicate((documentName, apiDescription) =>
    {
        var actionApiVersionModel = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor
        .GetApiVersionModel(ApiVersionMapping.Explicit | ApiVersionMapping.Implicit);

        if (actionApiVersionModel == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (actionApiVersionModel.DeclaredApiVersions.Any())
        {
            return actionApiVersionModel.DeclaredApiVersions.Any(v =>
            $"TestDocumentOpenAPISpecificationv{v.ToString()}" == documentName);
        }

        return actionApiVersionModel.ImplementedApiVersions.Any(v =>
            $"TestDocumentOpenAPISpecificationv{v.ToString()}" == documentName);
    });

    //var xmlCommentsFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    //var xmlCommentsFullPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlCommentsFile);

    //options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlCommentsFullPath);
});
```

**Configure:**

```cs
app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    foreach (var description in apiVersionDescriptionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint(
            $"/swagger/TestDocumentOpenAPISpecification{description.GroupName}/swagger.json",
            $"Test Document API - {description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant()}");
    }
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;

    options.DefaultModelExpandDepth(2);
    options.DefaultModelRendering(Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.ModelRendering.Model);
    options.DocExpansion(Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.DocExpansion.None);
    options.DisplayRequestDuration();
    options.EnableValidator();
    options.EnableFilter();
    options.EnableDeepLinking();
    options.DisplayOperationId();
});
```

The swagger generated makes `anotherId` mandatory in both the routes. It's was not like that previously. I tried adding `Name` to both routes but still it fails. Please assist on where I'm wrong.

Comment: I think this is behaving as intended, but if you think it is not, then this is a bug and you should report it: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/new

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I have logged this as issue in their repo. Let's wait for their reply on this. Here is the [issue link](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1572)

Comment: You got an answer:  `the Swagger/OpenAPI specification DOES NOT allow optional route parameters. So, while youre filter MAY be sufficient to meet your needs, the resulting Swagger/JSON is technically invalid.` The consequences of an invalid Swagger might not be obvious until you try to use it with some other automation tool.

Comment: Yeah I understand. Thanks for the support. Unfortunately my api is in production. hence I'm forced to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some analysis I have made this to work using `IOperationFilter`.

```cs
public class DeleteOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.ApiDescription.HttpMethod == "DELETE" && context.MethodInfo.Name == "Delete")
        {
            foreach (var parameter in context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions)
            {
                if (parameter.RouteInfo == null)
                {
                    operation.Parameters.Single(x => x.Name.Equals(parameter.Name)).Required = false;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And adding it in the `ConfigureServices`,

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    ...
    options.OperationFilter<DeleteOperationFilter>();
};
```

Am not sure this is the best way, but this works. Please correct me if I'm wrong.